# Monitor Asterisk Extensions On a Web Page

Tags: javascript, .net, asterisk, asteriskami

I've been looking around for a way to monitor asterisk extensions, just like a BLF, using a web page.
I'm building an ASP.NET web app to integrate with the users phones,
and I want 300 users having the extensions field on their web page updating in real time.
I know FOP2 does that pretty neatly.

I'm not expecting anyone to lay down a perfect solution for me,
just a general directaion.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Use AMI to read a list of SIP devices, then use that list to query the device status of each SIP device.  Then show the icon status of each SIP device.

Without knowing more of your use-case, that's about as exact as I can get.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Device+State

Comment: How can I do so using .NET? without having to refresh the page each second in order to get acrruate results.
Is there a way to do this using a client side script?

Comment: You'll need to open a telnet session via .NET for the AMI and then process the interactions.  I don't have any sample code for you, but you may be able to find a .NET AMI library via Google search.